# Is it possible to generate code for WS operations from eclipse web services explorer?

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I have successfully tested WS operation from eclipse WS explorer. I have problems with programming all the neccessary parameters for WS operation (lots of non Java types). I created my WS client from wizard.

Is it possbile to generate code that would call the same operation as in WS explorer?

If that can't be done, what is the best way to view outgoing SOAP request so i can better see which parameter is null/missing? I am tunneling my connection to the WS endpoint, so i can't see packets with e.g. Wireshark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TCP/IP monitor of Eclipse to monitor web services.
Check: [Using the TCP/IP Monitor to test Web services](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.wsi.ui.doc.user/tasks/tmonitor.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOAPUI to view the soap request and responses. Also you can refer to the section 9.5 of the notes below: -
http://www.slideshare.net/krizsan/scdjws-5-study-notes-3085287